# How to skip attributes/key in JSON output?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rabl, ruby-grape

Images Model contain id, file_name and description. Gem: either RABL or GRAPE

The usual output is:

```
{
    "images": [
        {
            "id": 48660,
            "file_name": "9e0f6.jpg",
            "description": "View 1"
        },
        {
            "id": 48665,
            "file_name": "fd42f.jpg",
            "description": "View 2"
        },
        {
            "id": 48662,
            "file_name": "477e8.jpg",
            "description": "View 3"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I remove the attributes/keys and convert the values to an array as follows?

```
{
    "images":[
        [
            48660,
            "9e0f6.jpg",
            "View 1"
        ],
        [
            48665,
            "fd42f.jpg",
            "View 2"
        ],
        [
            48662,
            "477e8.jpg",
            "View 3"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert it into a hash by using

```
JSON.parse(json)
```

and reconstruct the json without the keys

```
json_hash = JSON.parse(json)

inner_array = []
json_hash["images"].each do |elem|
  inner_array << elem.collect{|key, value| value unless ["file_name"].include?(key)}
end

json_hash["images"] = inner_array
json_hash.to_json
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works. I had ignored some attributes in the JSON. How do i selectively display attributes? Like now created_at and updated_at attributes are also being displayed.

Comment: Hey could you pls tell me how to ignore an attribute/key, say suppose from the above example : file_name. So only two out of three fields will be displayed

Comment: Updated the answer. You can add more attributes to the array if you want to ignore those